# MySQL LIKE, effect of extra wildcards on performance

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-like, text-search

Say I have a set of database rows containing data like:

- Blah1-Blah2-Blah3
- Blah1-Blah3-Blah2

Would a LIKE query using "Blah1-%" be faster/slower than a query using "Blah1-%-%". Obviously in my example they will retrieve both rows, but hopefully you get where I'm coming from; is it better to include all the information you have in regards to what the string contains to the query, or omit information if you can.

My thinking is more information in the query could lead to an index being better utilised, or because its a more complex query it would actually slow it down. I've got a decent amount of experience with databases but haven't got my head around what a key does on a technical level; this might be a stupid question to someone who knows!

Comment: are we talking a free text field here?

Comment: Yes we are! Although if there is a better method of storing the data for this type of search...?

Comment: if the values going into this fields is free text then an index is not going to help really, I can say though that any string comparisons are going to be heavier on the query optimiser if you test for a value anywhere in the string than say testing the beginning of the string. - I would suggest that where possible you make a pre determined list of selectable values which can be indexed instead?

Answer (score 0):

`"Blah1-%-%"` would not find `"Blah1-foo"`, but the other one would.  That aside,...

The main time involved in a query is fetching the row, especially if it needs to be red from disk, and parsing it.  The cost of any expressions, include `LIKE` with an extra wildcard, are minor.

All the Optimizer does with `LIKE` is decide whether it starts with a wildcard (thereby not allowing an index) or not (thereby letting the Optimizer consider an index).